# What does カンベン mean here?

Tags: meaning

A middle-aged man who somehow transformed into his younger self was smoking out of habit and he wondered

> 今俺がこの姿で吸い続けて元に戻った時、その辺どうなのかなって、突然肺がんとかカンベンなんだけど

I don't understand what カンベン means in this context. Its usual meaning of "forgive" does not make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The base meaning of 勘弁 is indeed "to forgive". One of the most common usage patterns is 勘弁してください, which expresses a polite yet strong refusal, like begging for mercy ("Oh please don't ～", "I beg you, no ～").

> 内視鏡は勘弁してください。
> I really hope I can avoid the endoscopy.

By further extension, 勘弁だ can express a simple strong refusal. It often implies that the situation is seen as an unjustified punishment or treatment.

> 内視鏡は勘弁だ。
> Endoscopy is a definite no-go.